# perl Slicing out the second field of each array line

Tags: arrays, perl, slice

I am loading this data into an array, it prints out ok. However what I am trying to do is read the file line by line and then load the whole line into another array, and then just print out the second field of that second array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @fields;

while ( my $line = <DATA> )  {

    @fields = split /,/, $line;

    foreach my $field ( @fields ) {   

        push ( my @one_line_array, $field );
        print my "$one_line_array[1]\n" ;
    }
}

__DATA__

BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_01_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_01_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_02_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_02_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_03_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_03_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script03'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_04_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script04'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_04_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script04'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_05_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script05'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_06_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script06'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_07_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_07_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script07'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_08_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script08'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_08_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script08'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_09_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script09'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_09_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script09'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_10_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script10'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_10_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script10'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_11_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script11'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_11_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script11'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_12_PS, europe-linux.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script12'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_13_PS, europe-linux.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script13'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_14_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script14'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_15_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script15'
 BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_16_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/csh -c '$HOME/TRADEDATE.pl'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_17_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/csh -c '$HOME/TRADEDATE.pl'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_01_17, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script17'
PROD, CAPSER_PROD_JOB_18_PS, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script18'
BACKUP, CAPSER_JOB_19_PP, usa-penguin.com, /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script19'
```

I can print out this when I print out the first array - so that works :

```
 BACKUP
 CAPSER_JOB_01_PP
 usa-penguin.com
 /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'

PROD
 CAPSER_PROD_JOB_01_PS
 usa-penguin.com
 /bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/run.sh'

BACKUP
 CAPSER_JOB_02_PP
 usa-penguin.com
 /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'

PROD
 CAPSER_PROD_JOB_02_PS
 usa-penguin.com
 /bin/bash -lc '$HOME/run/script02'
```

However when I create the second array, what I am trying to print out is just the 2nd field from that array:

```
 CAPSER_JOB_01_PP
 CAPSER_PROD_JOB_01_PS
 CAPSER_JOB_02_PP
 CAPSER_PROD_JOB_02_PS
```

I get these errors when I try to get the second field of the second array. When I initialize it with "my" I get a compilation error. I do mot know how to slice out every second field.

```
 casper@casper.com 1066$ ./casper_test2.pl
Use of uninitialized value $one_line_array[1] in concatenation (.) or    string at ./casper_test2.pl line 13, <DATA> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $one_line_array[1] in concatenation (.) or string at ./casper_test2.pl line 13, <DATA> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $one_line_array[1] in concatenation (.) or string at ./casper_test2.pl line 13, <DATA> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $one_line_array[1] in concatenation (.) or string at ./casper_test2.pl line 13, <DATA> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $one_line_array[1] in concatenation (.) or string at ./casper_test2.pl line 13, <DATA> line 2.

casper@casper.com 1068$ ./casper_test2.pl
syntax error at ./casper_test2.pl line 13, near "my "$one_line_array[1]\n""
Execution of ./casper_test2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
casper@casper.com1069$
```

@Diab Jerius -- This actually gives me what I need for now:

```
 while (my $line = <DATA> ) {
     @fields = split /,/, $line ;
     print "$fields[1]\n" ;
 }
```

Comment: the line `push (my @one_line_array ,  $field);` declares a new array at every iteration of `foreach` in which it runs, then it adds an element to it.  So there is one element in a (new) array with that name in every iteration.  Declare at a higher scope.

Comment: Perl arrays are zero offset, so `$one_line_array[1]` prints out the _second_ element of the array.

Comment: Yes I want to get the second field of each line in the __DATA__ set. I am not using awk because I need to do something with the second field in perl

Comment: @zdim  - I do not know what you mean by declaring it at a higher scope

Comment: @Diab Jerius - yes that is what I want - I want the second field of each line in the __DATA__ set

Comment: If all you want is the second field, you could replace the entire `foreach` loop with `print $field[1], "\n";`

Comment: @Diab Jerius --  well I am going to have to pull out the second field and then use a substring on it and then shoot it to another function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157518/discussion-between-diab-jerius-and-capser).

Answer (score 0):

The problem which I see is in the below line:

```
print my "$one_line_array[1]\n" ; #Why you using my here...!
```

Secondly you can directly try printing the $field[1] just inside the loop to see whether you are getting the right values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @fields;

while ( my $line = <DATA> )  {

    @fields = split /,/, $line;
    print $fields[1];

}
```

Updated...

Comment: Your code doesn't work. There is no `@field` so you can't print `$field[1]`

Comment: Check now, it should be fine now

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the second field, then you can do your thing with `map`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @second_col = map { (split /,/) [1] } <DATA>;

print Dumper \@second_col;
```

You can also substring/transform it at the same time, if that's your use case:

```
my @trimmed_second_col = map { (split /,/)[1] =~ s/\s+//gr } <DATA>;
print Dumper \@trimmed_second_col;
```

This iterates by line of `<DATA>`, splits each one on `,`, and then applies a 'remove whitespace' regex, which - thanks to the `r` flag returns the result, and that gets stored into `@trimmed_second_col`.

But the reason you're having problems I think, is because you're misunderstanding a few things - you're pushing for each iteration of a loop, which means you're doing it too many times. And you're misusing `my`.

What `my` does is declare a variable that's private to the current scope. So if you use it *within* a foreach loop, it's creating a *new* array each time, that vanishes again when the loop iterates. Particularly with the `print` that's meaningless.

So how about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @second_col;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my @row = split /,/; 
   # if you need to preserve it in an array.
   push @second_col, $row[1];    

   #or if you just need to print it:
   print $row[1],"\n";
}

print Dumper \@second_col;
```